# building otool on my mac gives Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, macos, cmake

So I downloaded otool from apple open source website:
https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/cctools/cctools-895.tar.gz

Then I use CLion (an IDE) open otool and try to build it. CLion seems generates a `CMakeLists.txt` for me, and when I click build, it says:

```
[ 89%] Building C object CMakeFiles/otool.dir/print_objc2_64bit.c.o
[ 94%] Building C object CMakeFiles/otool.dir/sparc_disasm.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable otool
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SWAP_DOUBLE", referenced from:
      _print_ef in m68k_disasm.c.o
      _print_literal8_section in ofile_print.c.o
      _print_literal_pointer_section in ofile_print.c.o
  "_SWAP_FLOAT", referenced from:
      _print_insn_neon in arm_disasm.c.o
      _print_ef in m68k_disasm.c.o
      _print_literal4_section in ofile_print.c.o
  "_SWAP_LONG_LONG", referenced from:
      _guess_pointer_pointer in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _guess_pointer_pointer in i386_disasm.c.o
      _print_library_toc in ofile_print.c.o
      _print_literal_pointer_section in ofile_print.c.o
      _print_init_term_pointer_section in ofile_print.c.o
      _walk_pointer_list in print_objc2_64bit.c.o
      _swap_cfstring_t in print_objc2_64bit.c.o
      ...
  "_allocate", referenced from:
      _method_reference in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _get_dyld_bind_info in dyld_bind_info.c.o
      _method_reference in i386_disasm.c.o
      _main in main.c.o
      _processor in main.c.o
      _setup_dyld_bind_info in main.c.o
      _print_text in main.c.o
      ...
  "_apple_version", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
      _version in main.c.o
  "_arch_usage", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_assemble_12", referenced from:
      _hppa_disassemble in hppa_disasm.c.o
  "_assemble_17", referenced from:
      _hppa_disassemble in hppa_disasm.c.o
  "_assemble_21", referenced from:
      _hppa_disassemble in hppa_disasm.c.o
  "_assemble_3", referenced from:
      _hppa_disassemble in hppa_disasm.c.o
  "_error", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
      _print_bitcode_section in print_bitcode.c.o
      _print_xar_files_summary in print_bitcode.c.o
  "_error_with_arch", referenced from:
      _print_library_toc in ofile_print.c.o
      _print_sysv_library_toc in ofile_print.c.o
  "_errors", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_get_arch_from_flag", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_get_host_byte_sex", referenced from:
      _arm64_disassemble in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _guess_pointer_pointer in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _guess_cstring_pointer in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _guess_literal_pointer in arm_disasm.c.o
      _guess_cstring_pointer in arm_disasm.c.o
      _print_insn_neon in arm_disasm.c.o
      _print_coff_reloc_section in coff_print.c.o
      ...
  "_get_stack_addr_from_flag", referenced from:
      _print_argstrings in main.c.o
  "_get_toc_byte_sex", referenced from:
      _processor in main.c.o
  "_guess_short_name", referenced from:
      _setup_dyld_bind_info in main.c.o
      _print_hints in ofile_print.c.o
  "_llvm_create_disasm", referenced from:
      _create_arm64_llvm_disassembler in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _create_arm_llvm_disassembler in arm_disasm.c.o
      _create_thumb_llvm_disassembler in arm_disasm.c.o
      _create_i386_llvm_disassembler in i386_disasm.c.o
      _create_x86_64_llvm_disassembler in i386_disasm.c.o
  "_llvm_disasm_dispose", referenced from:
      _delete_arm64_llvm_disassembler in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _delete_arm_llvm_disassembler in arm_disasm.c.o
      _delete_thumb_llvm_disassembler in arm_disasm.c.o
      _delete_i386_llvm_disassembler in i386_disasm.c.o
      _delete_x86_64_llvm_disassembler in i386_disasm.c.o
  "_llvm_disasm_instruction", referenced from:
      _arm64_disassemble in arm64_disasm.c.o
      _print_insn in arm_disasm.c.o
      _i386_disassemble in i386_disasm.c.o
  "_llvm_disasm_set_options", referenced from:
      _print_text in main.c.o
  "_llvm_disasm_version_string", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_low_sign_ext", referenced from:
      _hppa_disassemble in hppa_disasm.c.o
  "_makestr", referenced from:
      _print_bitcode_section in print_bitcode.c.o
  "_ofile_process", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
  "_reallocate", referenced from:
      _main in main.c.o
      _print_text in main.c.o
      _print_reloc in ofile_print.c.o
      _print_indirect_symbols in ofile_print.c.o
      _print_hints in ofile_print.c.o
      _print_literal_pointer_section in ofile_print.c.o
      _get_objc_sections in print_objc.c.o
      ...
  "_reloc_has_pair", referenced from:
      _get_symbol_32 in print_objc2_32bit.c.o
      _get_symbol_64 in print_objc2_64bit.c.o
  "_sign_ext", referenced from:
      _hppa_disassemble in hppa_disasm.c.o
      _print_immediate in hppa_disasm.c.o
  "_size_ar_name", referenced from:
      _print_ar_hdr in ofile_print.c.o
  "_swap_arm_thread_state64_t", referenced from:
      _print_thread_states in ofile_print.c.o
  "_swap_arm_thread_state_t", referenced from:
      _print_thread_states in ofile_print.c.o
  "_swap_base_relocation_block_header", referenced from:
      _print_coff_reloc_section in coff_print.c.o
  "_swap_base_relocation_entry", referenced from:
      _print_coff_reloc_section in coff_print.c.o
  "_swap_data_in_code_entry", referenced from:
      _processor in main.c.o
  "_swap_ppc_thread_state64_t", referenced from:
      _print_thread_states in ofile_print.c.o
  "_swap_twolevel_hint", referenced from:
      _processor in main.c.o
  "_swap_xar_header", referenced from:
      _print_bitcode_section in print_bitcode.c.o
  "_system_error", referenced from:
      _print_bitcode_section in print_bitcode.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [otool] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/otool.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/otool.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [otool] Error 2
```

Here's the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(otool)
include_directories( ../include )
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES
        arm64_disasm.c
        arm64_disasm.h
        arm_disasm.c
        arm_disasm.h
        coff_print.c
        cxa_demangle.h
        dyld_bind_info.c
        dyld_bind_info.h
        hppa_disasm.c
        hppa_disasm.h
        i386_disasm.c
        i386_disasm.h
        i860_disasm.c
        i860_disasm.h
        m68k_disasm.c
        m68k_disasm.h
        m88k_disasm.c
        m88k_disasm.h
        main.c
        notify.c
        notify.h
        ofile_print.c
        ofile_print.h
        otool.h
        ppc_disasm.c
        ppc_disasm.h
        print_bitcode.c
        print_objc.c
        print_objc2_32bit.c
        print_objc2_64bit.c
        sparc_disasm.c
        sparc_disasm.h)


add_executable(otool ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I don't know CMake a lot, how can I fix it? Specifically, how do I know which lib is causing the problem, and how do I add them into the CMakeLists? Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463895/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-glbegin?rq=1' since it is about the same architecture and has the same problem.

Comment: The most likely cause of the problem is the resulting compile statement is missing the `-I<header path>` statement and/or the resulting link statement is missing the `-L<lib path>` and/or `-l<short lib name>`   Since the error messages are from the linker, most likely the link statement is missing one or more libraries or the library path is missing or not correct